# Como setar uma valor no select que é montado com ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Meu HTML é assim:

```
<select ng-model="cliente" ng-options="t.value as t.displayName for t in clientes"></select>
```

No Controlador do meu JS tenho:

```
$scope.clientes // objeto onde tem todos os clientes para alimentar o select
$scope.cliente // esse é o meu ng-model
```

Meu select está funcionando perfeitamente, consigo obter os dados e salvar eles. Minha duvida é a seguinte, como faço para preencher esse select via javascript? Eu pensei que quando eu coloca-se um valor no `$scope.cliente` ele iria funcionar, mas não funcionou!

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Continuei testando aqui e descobri a solução.

No meu $scope.cliente eu estava setando um valor do tipo `number` e tem que ser do tipo `string`.

Ex:
Eu troquei isso:

```
$scope.cliente = 1;
```

Por isso:

```
$scope.cliente = '1';
```

E funcionou!

Abraços