# Selects selecionados a partir de objeto

Tags: angularjs

Os inputs do tipo select não vem selecionados quando carrego um form a partir de um objeto. Os valores do select estão definidos no controller. Como faço para carregar a página e os selects serem selecionados com os valores do objeto?

Por exemplo, se o valor do tipo do projeto é 2, o select vem selecionado com a opção com valor 2.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="tipo" ng-model="vm.projeto.tipo" ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in vm.tipos">
    <option value="">Selecione o tipo projeto</option>
</select>
```

Ctrl:

```
vm.projeto = {
    nome: "Projeto 1",
    tipo: 2
};

vm.tipos = {
    1: "Tipo 1", 
    2: "Tipo 2", 
    3: "Tipo 3"
};
```

**EDIT:** Neste post: [Como setar uma valor no select que é montado com ng-options](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65543/como-setar-uma-valor-no-select-que-%C3%A9-montado-com-ng-options?rq=1), a solução foi usar um valor do tipo string no lugar de number, porém fiz o teste e não deu certo, o curioso é que assim ele parece mudar a opção e volta para o default bem rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi alterando o `ng-options` e a lista `vm.tipos`. Ficou assim:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="tipo" ng-model="vm.projeto.tipo" ng-options="tipo.valor as tipo.descricao for tipo in vm.tipos">
    <option value="">Selecione o tipo projeto</option>
</select>
```

Ctrl:

```
vm.projeto = {
    nome: "Projeto 1",
    tipo: 2
};

vm.tipos = [
  {valor: 1, descricao: "Tipo 1"},
  {valor: 2, descricao: "Tipo 2"},
  {valor: 3, descricao: "Tipo 3"}
];
```

Agora todos os `selects` já vem com a opção selecionada de acordo o `objeto` do `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

Vais ter que usar um dos modos de iteração sobe o objecto e produzir cada `option` daí.

Podes usar o `ng-repeat` ou o `ng-options`. Eu prefiro a ng-options porque nao temos que fazer a interpolação do nosso output uma vez que a directiva trata disso.

Sem mudar a sua estrutura de código, também é possivel fazer o que queres;

```
  <select name="selected" id="selected" ng-model="selecionado_2">
    <option ng-repeat="(tipo, nome) in tipos track by $index" value="{{tipo}}">{{nome}}</option>
  </select>
  Selecionado: {{::selecionado_2}}
```

---

Organizando o teu codigo e usando `ng-options`

```
function Types($scope) {

  $scope.selecionado = {};
  $scope.types = [
    { valor: 1, nome: "Tipo 1"},
    { valor: 2, nome: "Tipo 2"},
    { valor: 3, nome: "Tipo 3"},
    { valor: 4, nome: "Tipo 4"},
    { valor: 5, nome: "Tipo 5"}
  ]
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Types', Types);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);

<body ng-controller="Types">

  <select name="selected" id="selected" ng-model="selecionado" 
          ng-options="type.nome for type in types track by type.valor">
    <option value="">---Seleciona um Tipo---</option>
  </select>
  Selecionado: {{selecionado}}
</body>
```

Basicamente, usamos a directiva `ng-options` para iterar sobe o nosso objecto `types` que contém o valor do tipo e o nome do tipo.

Tens aqui o [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/940a8hk8/1/)